# Not getting displayed mathematical equation in Google Blogger?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to create a blog. In that, I have to show some mathematical equations. But, I am not able to see the same equation on the page. Here, is my analysis about the same

Before the `</head>` tag I have placed the below code, which will convert normal script into Mathematical equation.

```
<script src='http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js' type='text/javascript'>    
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    HTML: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
    TeX: { extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js"], 
           equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } },
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
               displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
               processEscapes: true },
    "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"],
                  linebreaks: { automatic: true } }
});
</script>
```

After that I have  placed my equation which I need to see on the screen is below.

```
n^4+〖2n〗^2+ 100n+500≈ n^4
```

Can anyone help me, how to see the above code line into mathematical equation.

Comment: I don't know where this will be an on-topic question, but this site isn't it; this is for people using the software *Mathematica* by Wolfram Research.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Try putting the <script></script> tags containing the Javascript into the head section of your HTML document and add something like the following to the body:  `<p> $$ n^4+ (2n)^2+ 100n+500≈ n^4 $$</p>`.  An example is [here](https://mathjax-example.firebaseapp.com/). Note that I used the [https](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html) (rather than http) version of the CDN to deploy to [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), but the script was otherwise identical to yours.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.